# Are there any CPU-state bits indicating being in an exception/interrupt handler in ARM Cortex-A processors?

Tags: exception, arm, cpu-registers, interrupt-handling, cortex-a

Are there any `CPU-state` bits indicating being in an exception/interrupt handler in `ARM Cortex-A` processors (like e.g. `IPSR` reister in `ARM Cortex-M` CPUs)? In other words, can we tell whether the main thread or exception handler is currently executed based only on the `CPU` registers' state?

Answer (score 0):

The CPSR mode field indicates what mode the processor is currently executing in.  You cannot act on it directly, you have to move it into a gpr to examine it.